# Why section "Native" uses so much RAM?

Tags: java, android, native, ram

[image: Do someone have an idear why native uses so much RAM?]

It's nearly the same usage over all activities. If I manually let the garbage collector run I could decrease it to 80MB total usage but used ram by "Native" stays all the time the highs, min, 60MB.

My total Ram record was 1,4GB (so android settings shows) what is going on there?

Is it relevant information, that my app uses app bundler und at the moment 2 packages?

Comment: Doesn't mean that the frameworks you use don't use native memory.  The Android interface toolkit uses memory.  What you can do is start removing stuff from your app and see if something in particular makes a big difference.  The VM is going to reserve memory for the compiler actions and code optimizations as well.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the Java Android APIs are in the end calling native functions and therefore also consuming native memory. For example when using the camera to take photos and showing preview on the screen, all the handling of the data coming from the camera's frame buffer is written in native (C or C++) code which is more performant than when it would have been written in Java.

So what can you do to reduce native memory usage? Not much because the native implementation is hopefully well-designed and can not be changed anyway, but you could consider these points:

- include or link only the libraries you actually need
- use the libraries and APIs only when and where needed
- free resources as soon as possible (e.g. recycling bitmaps)
- configure the APIs and libraries for less memory usage (if supported)